# Unable to find match in database SQLite-Database with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I am building a level-system for a Discord-bot, where I have one sqlite-table with the user and the xp and another table with the level and the minimum and maximum-xp:

[image]

My idea is that a user can enter `!level` which finds his id in the user-database (This is already working) and then finds his level by looking where his xp is bigger than the minimum of a level and smaller than the maximum of a level.

**Example:** I have 15 xp. Level 1 goes from 0 to 10 and Level 2 from 11 to 20. Since 15 is between 11 and 20 I am level 2

My code so far goes as following:

```js
 try {
            //Find the user by searching through the database with the id
            const match = await level.findOne({where: {user_id: userID}});

            //If a match was found
            if(match) {

                const userLevel = await xp.findOne({ 
                    where: {
                        //Find the level by looking where match.xp is greater or equal than the minimum
                        minimum: {
                            [Sequelize.gte]: match.xp
                        },
                        //and where match.xp is smaller or equal than the maximum
                        maximum: {
                            [Sequelize.lte]: match.xp
                        }
                    }
                })

                //If the level was found
                if(userLevel) {

                    //Do something with the result
                    
                }
                else {
                    message.channel.send("I cannot find that level because I am stupid")
                }
                
            }
            else {
                message.channel.send("I was unable to find that profile")
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
```

The problem is that no matter what kind of XP I have the bot never finds a match for the level. According to the [Sequelize-docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html) `Sequelize.gte` and `Sequelize.lte` are the correct terms I need.

Here is a screenshot of the XP-Database
[image]

And here of the User-Database: [image]